# Regression on SQL Server Connection from Standard Logic App

Tags: sql-server, connection, azure-logic-apps

I have been developing Standard Logic Apps with SQL Server successfully for some time, but suddenly can no longer connect. I'm using Azure AD Integrated as my Authentication Type, which I know is OK as I use the same credentials in SSMS. If I try to create a new credential, it is *apparently* successful but on save the Logic App says "The API connection reference XXX is missing or not valid". Something has changed, but I don't know what ... help!

Comment: [dup on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/690590/regression-on-sql-server-connection-from-standard.html)

Comment: This could be because there is no XXX connection in the current Flow. If you test it with a recently used trigger, it will automatically throw an error.

Try changing every connection related to the sql (i.e.. the actions which are connected to old credentials) change it to new credentials connection.

Comment: This issue is current the subject of the M/S ticket; if anything worth sharing emerges, I'll post it here

Comment: @JohnD Any updates on this? If not would you mind adding code view of your logic app?

Answer (score 0):

per above, this was submitted to M/S and has been resolved as follows: the root cause is if a Logic App Parameter name includes an *embedded space* the problem with SQL connections is triggered. This is a pernicious problem, as the error message is quite unrelated to the root cause. Further, since embedded spaces are supported in Logic Apps e.g. in Step Names, it is easy to assume the same applies across the board.